# error appearing while retrieving data form fire-base

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[while retrieving data from firebase this is being immediately shown on the screen and within a few milliseconds of the error shown in the image is disappearing and the data retrieved is being shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joU1X.jpg)

after showing the error, which you can see in the image provided. this error sustains for only a few milliseconds, and in no time the data is being shown.

```
Widget listitems(){
return new StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('inventory').snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
     return new ListView(
      children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
        return Card(
          margin: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0,5.0,10.0,5.0),
          elevation: 10.0,
          child: new Container(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25.0,25.0,25.0,25.0),
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text('Name of the Item:         '+document['name'],
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,fontWeight:FontWeight.w600),),
                new SizedBox(height: 1.0,),
                new Text('Category of the Item:    ' +document['category'],
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,fontWeight:FontWeight.w300),),
                new SizedBox(height: 1.0,),
                new Text('Quantity of the Item:     '+document['quantity']+ 'items',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,fontWeight:FontWeight.w300),),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }

 );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error makes sense. It is because it takes a few milliseconds to retrieve the data from Firestore (or for any other API call for that matter).

What you can do is to check if you've received the data and return the widgets only when you have it. For example :

```
  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection(documentName).snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, 
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
       case ConnectionState.waiting:
           return Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator());
       default:
           return ListView(.............);
      }
    },
  );
}
```